# How to run through a list of variables as part of a file path?

Tags: python

I need to go through a series of identical directories and combine two .txt files from each into a single file.

I tried using a list (partial list included, in total ~1000 directories) but Python keeps interpreting my list variable as text in the file path.

```
import os
for subject in ['100307', '100408', '101107']:
    os.chdir("/Users/me/Desktop/SubjPerformance/(subject)")

    filenames = ['0bk_nlr.txt', '2bk_nlr.txt']

    with open('all_bk_nlr', 'w') as outfile:
        for fname in filenames:
            with open(fname) as infile:
               outfile.write(infile.read())
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/me/Desktop/SubjPerformance/(subject)'
```

Obviously, (subject) is not part of the file path. I want it to take an item from my list, but it is interpreting what I want to be a list variable as text instead.

I'm sure this could also be done with a wildcard character that runs through every subdirectory within /SubjPerformance but I don't know how to build that loop.

Thanks for your help, and sorry for the ignorant question--I'm a neuroscience researcher, not a developer!

Comment: Python won't interpret the text as a variable. You can concatenate the variable with your string in various ways depending on the python version you are running: `"string" + variable` or `f'string{variable}'` or `'string{}'.format(variable)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use a variable inside a string, you can use `"/Users/me/Desktop/SubjPerformance/%s" % subject`. You can learn more about string formatting [here](https://www.learnpython.org/en/String_Formatting).

Answer (score 1):

You use incorrect syntax, use

```py
"/Users/me/Desktop/SubjPerformance/%s" % subject
```

or

```py
"/Users/me/Desktop/SubjPerformance/{}".format(subject)
```

instead.